# python26.dll was not found

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

When I try `pyuic4 -o hello.py hello.ui` in command prompt, an error occurs saying

> python26.dll was not found

I downloaded the same and copied in `C:\windows\system32\...`. But now I'm getting the following error:

```
C:\>pyuic4 -o hello.py hello.ui
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\pyuic.py", line 4, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtCore
ImportError: Module use of python26.dll conflicts with this version of Python.
```

whats the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> i installed PyQt-Py2.6-gpl-4.7-1.exe and python-2.5.msi

Binary packages are compiled against a specific python version.
You should always install the  binary package corresponding to your installed python version. The python version is often indicated in the name of the package. In your case, `Py2.6` indicates that this PyQt distribution is to be installed with Python 2.6.

Answer (score 2):

python26.dll is part of your Python installation (check the root directory, /lib and /bin subdirectories of your python installation; try to add that directory to the PATH). As you installed another python26.dll, it obviously won't necessarily match your python installation. Remove the downloaded python26.dll. Also, don't install such libraries to system paths like windows\system32, that's a sure recipe for problems.

Comment: i installed  PyQt-Py2.6-gpl-4.7-1.exe and python-2.5.msi...but python26.dll is not created ...

Comment: Did you try to install python 2.6? The PyQt filename and the dll name suggest that it requires Python 2.6.